# Woocommerce customer quit before Paypal redirect

Tags: paypal, wordpress, paypal-ipn, paypal-pdt

I setup a Woocommerce website with Paypal and I linked a PDT token to it. When my customer buy something with Paypal they get redirect to Paypal -> Pay their items -> get redirect to the thank you page of my woocommerce.

During this last step some of my client quit Paypal website before they get redirect back to Woocommerce. Their order is now stuck on pending payment.

Is it normal to ask my customer to wait 10 seconds or click here to have their order completed.

Comment: Not exactly directly related,but I think there is a rule which says if the visitor waits for more than 4 seconds for a request there is a high probability he will leave.Maybe change host

Comment: paypal is pretty slow in this set up anyway, try stripe payments who handle the process without leaving your site.

Comment: @Mihai The wait time is on paypal side. I'd love to redirect quicker but I can't

Answer (score 0):

When using PayPal Standard (which is what comes with WooCommerce by default) then yes, it's normal for the user to have to wait "up to 10 seconds" for the redirect, even with Auto-Return enabled in your PayPal account.

If you want to provide a better experience it would be recommended to enable PayPal Express Checkout instead of PayPal Standard.  This can be done using the free [PayPal for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/) plugin.